# How to make a complex grid layout with the Omega theme?

Tags: theming

How do I make a complex grid layout with the Omega theme where regions can be embedded in regions? I included an image of how I want the page layout to be set. Right now I'm thinking that I will use the CSS property in the Views UI to manually set the grid-[columns] and alpha or omega properties of the Views block. Is there a better way of doing this so the code is in a logical place and not a hack?
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For something like this, I will simply use the [Block Class](http://drupal.org/project/block_class) module and for the blocks I'm placing inside a region, add a grid-X and alpha/omega appropriate classes as needed.

I've never found the reason (even in really advanced layouts/designs/grids) to do anything more than that...

Comment: What I realized is that it didn't help changing the view css because it wrapped in block markup neither did using a view attachment. Rather than have another database query I just went ahead and added the class into a helper module through HOOK_preprocess_block(&$vars). `function helper_preprocess_block(&$vars) {
  
  if ($vars['block']->delta == "50a597852ade9b54514cbd206a5baa2a") {
    $vars['classes_array'] = array_merge($vars['classes_array'], array('grid-4 omega'));
  }

}`

Answer (score 0):

Use the views_column_class module (http://drupal.org/project/views_column_class).

This lets you add alpha, omega and other settings to views so that they don't break your grid.